# First two moments of the ratio of the geometric mean to the arithmetic mean of Gamma random variables

Tags: mean, gamma-distribution

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be $n$ uncorrelated  random variables from a Gamma distribution with **different parameters**: $X_i \sim Gamma(k_i, \theta_i)$. What is the distribution of $$ U=\log \left[ \dfrac{\bar{X}}{\tilde{X}}\right]$$
where $\bar{X}$ is the sample arithmetic mean and $\tilde{X}$  is the geometric mean.

EDIT: I don't necessarily need the distribution, the first 2 moments will suffice.

Comment: If $X_i$'s have different distributions, then do they form a 'sample' ?

Comment: Yes they do form a sample. Each $X_i$ is drawn from the same distribution but with different parameters (They are uncorrelated).

Comment: Is this for a subject/coursework/bookwork/self-study etc?

Comment: @Glen_b, No, I'm working on a new test statistic and I need the distribution of this statistic, at least its 2 first moments.

Comment: Taking the ratio of the GM to the AM in the gamma case isn't exactly new.

Comment: @Glen_b, you're right, but in my case, $X_i$'s aren't identically distrubuted.

Comment: With different parameters, there cannot be a simple expression to this distribution, since these parameters will not simplify into a summary.

Comment: @Xi'an, how about the first two moments, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: It appears that only the scale parameters $\theta_i$'s are different. Is that correct?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, my bad, the$k_i$'s are also different. Does it make it easier if only $\theta_i$'s were different?

Comment: @ToneyShields Of course it does. But if this is negotiable, it would be even better to have the $k_i$'s different and a common $\theta$.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, I can find the mgf If I had a common $\theta$. but unfortunately, it's not the case, but I'd like to see how to find the first 2 moments with a common $k$, please.

Comment: @ToneyShields, the post states "uncorrelated" is this truly what the assumption is or is the assumption "independent" which would imply "uncorrelated"?

Comment: @LucasRoberts, the assumption is uncorrelatedness.

Comment: @ToneyShields If this is for a test you're working on, then deriving the test statistic should at least get the person who answers co-authorship ;-)

Comment: @oneloop, I'm not asking for people to do this for me, I just want to know if this has already been done, or get some hints that might be useful.

Comment: @ToneyShields I was joking :-)

Comment: Well for the first moment of $U$, the main challenge is determining $E[ \log (\sum X_{i}) ]$. If the $k_{i}$ are identical, this article might be helpful for working that out: https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0505.

Comment: @Jason, actually $\sum X_i$ is a gamma distribution, which means that  $E(log (\sum X_i))$ is known.

Comment: @ToneyShields Can you clarify that point a little? I'm familiar with the fact that $\sum X_{i}$ is gamma if the $\theta_{i}$ are identical and the $X_{i}$ are independent, but not otherwise.

Comment: @Jason, if the $\theta_i$'s are not identical then we can consider each r.v. a scaled $\chi^2$, then $\sum X_i$ would be a sum of scaled $\chi^2$ r.v. which can be approximated by another scaled $\chi^2$ which would be a Gamma r.v.